# Getting a value/Returning something each time a thread executes its run

Tags: java, multithreading, return, frame, runnable

I have 2 threads running. One is a `TimeStepThread`, the other is a `CarThread`.
The `CarThread`runs every 500ms. The `TimeStepThread`runs at whatever interval I give it. Now, each 500ms, the `CarThread`updates the movement of car positions on the road. Each time the `TimeStepThread`is called however, I want to get that car position value. For instance, I have 1 car, which is updated every 500ms no matter what, but every 2 seconds I want to set a label with that car position.

My classes are set up like this:

1. `Simulation`class has a
2. `TimeStepThread`and a `CarThread`.

In my `Simulation`(or the frame, rather) I want to get the car position's value updated at every timestep interval. So every 2000ms, I need to update something/return something in/to the Simulation class.

Except I have no clue how to do this. Since my Threads are inside the  `Simulation`, I can't really call a  `Simulation` method from the `run()`, not to mention it would be a bit messy. Listeners, perhaps?

---

Edit: I can already access the cars in the timestep thread. This is not an issue. I'm using a container class which holds the cars, both threads can access and the `CarThread` updates it as well. My issue is about the Simulation class having an updated String, each time the TimeStepThread is called, or a Frame label being updated, each time the TimeStepThread is being called.

Answer (score 1):

The two classes, the ones in the two threads, both need access to the list of cars.

In this case the cars are instances of the car class.

The time step thread has a class that implements its work. (Which is reading the positions of the cars.)

The car thread has a class that implements its work. (Which is updating the positions.)

Each execution type class will access the car objects to either update them with position change info or to read out whatever. You will have to `synchronize` the instance methods in the car class (or the car container mentioned below) that access the position, for example, so the various threads won't step on each other.

There are two, similar ways to implement here.

1) Every time you create a car you pass it to each of the two work classes. They each keep their own internal list of all the cars. If you get rid of a car, you have to tell both of them.

2) At the start you give each of the two work classes a reference to a car container class. Maybe just a list--a concurrent list, though. Maybe a custom class. When you create a car, you tell the car container class (by adding it). When you lose a car, you tell it as well.

As for the Simulation class, you want it informed when the car's positions change. Again there are two ways, but they are similar.

In both cases, you will have to pass the simulation class instance to the class that is doing the updating. The simulation class has a method, say `updateCar()` that the the update class calls once it finishes updating.

1) Version 1 - the call to the simulation class instance only tells it that something has changed. The code in the simulation class will identify what has changed and deal with it OR it will just update everything.

2) Version 2 - the call to the simulation class instance will include a list of any cars that have been changed. The simulation class doesn't have to search to find what changed 
and it can update only the things changing.

The tricky part is that you have to remember that those calls to that update method are occuring in the update thread. So, for example, if you are using Swing to update text on the screen, you will have to use the SwingWorker to get the updates to happening in the event thread.

If you can't move that work to a safe thread, you will have to make sure all the right things are concurrent or synchronized so they don't step on each other.

Comment: My threads can already access the Car objects. Rephrased the question a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` in the `Simulation` class - the `Car` thread sends position updates to the queue.  The `Timestep` thread then processes all of the position updates (`poll` the queue until it returns empty) and places the labels.

Alternatively, you can put a `BlockingQueue` in the `Simulation` class, and have a thread continually `take` from the queue and update the position information.

This way you can add as may additional cars as you want without having to change the `Simulation` code - all of the cars send their updates to the same queue.

Answer (score 0):

I think a listener for you car progress is the best approach. You could something like

```
public interface CarProgressListener {
    void positionChanged(Position currentPosition);
}
```

then make your `TimestepThread` implement this interface and register it at `CarThread`.

```
public CarThread extends Thread {
     private final Collection<CarProgressListener> progressListeners = new LinkedList<>();
     // other stuff
     public void addListener(CarProgressListener listener) {
         this.progressListeners.add(listener);
     }
}

public TimestepThread extends Thread implements CarProgressListener {
     private Position lastHeardCarPosition;

     // remenber to initiate this thread with the first car position.

     @Override
     public void positionChanged(Position currentPosition) {
         this.lastHeardCarPosition = currentPosition;
     }
}
```

So, now in your `Simulation` class you will need to have something like

```
...
Position initialPosition = // get it from somewhere.
CarThread car = new CarThread(initialPosition);
TimestepThread timestepThread = new TimestepThread(initialPosition);

car.addListener(timestepThread);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a list or any other data structure. It could be as simple as this:

```
public class Car

    private volatile int position;


    public int getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public void setPosition(int position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

}

public class CarThread extends Thread {

    private final Car car;

    public CarThread(Car car) {
        this.car = car;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Thread.sleep(500);
        car.setPosition(//whatever)
    }
}

public class TimeStepThread extends Thread {

    private final Car car;

    public CarThread(Car car) {
        this.car = car;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        int position = car.getPosition()

        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Make sure you pass the same instance of Car to everything and you will be fine.

This answer also assumes that you don't need to queue up all the position changes, that only the most recent position is of any interest which, if you are using it to draw the location of the car on a map or something similar, is reasonable.

EDIT

To put it all together, try something like this:

```
public class TimeStepThread extends Thread {

    private final Car car;
    private final JFrame frame;


    public TimeStepThread(Car car, JFrame frame) {
        this.car = car;
        this.frame = frame;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    frame.setTitle(Integer.toString(car.getPosition()));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My threads can already access the Car objects. Rephrased the question a bit.

Comment: Sorry, then I don't understand the problem. Just call getPosition() every 2000ms from the TimeStepThread and you will see the latest value as calculated from the CarThread.

Comment: I don't need the value in the thread, I need the value in my Frame jLabel, to be updated every 2000ms.